# jquery detecting and removing an element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hierachy of DIVs with classes associated but not IDs. How can I remove the item being clicked?

```
<div>
    <div class="minibox" onclick="remove_me()">Box1</div>
    <div class="minibox" onclick="remove_me()">Box1</div>
    <div class="minibox" onclick="remove_me()">Box1</div>
    <div class="minibox" onclick="remove_me()">Box1</div>
    <div class="minibox" onclick="remove_me()">Box1</div>
</div>
<script>
    function remove_me(){
    ///remove the clicked div
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$('div .minibox').click(function(e){
    $(e.target).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$('.minibox').click(function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
 <div class="minibox" onclick="remove_me()">Box1</div>
```

to

```
 <div class="minibox" onclick="remove_me(this)">Box1</div>
```

then use

```
<script>
 function remove_me(elm){
   $(elm).remove();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the jQuery [document.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event, you need to bind a click handler to the `div`'s

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.minibox').click(function(e){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Check out jQuery [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) and [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

The `this` inside the event handler refers to the element that was clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box">Box 2</div>
<div class="box">Box 3</div>
<div class="box">Box 4</div>
<div class="box">Box 5</div>
```

then you would use

```
$(".box").bind("click", function() {

  $(this).fadeOut(500, function() { 
    // now that the fade completed
    $(this).remove(); 
  });

});
```

Example in [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/evibu4/edit)

Comment: `fadeIn` was a typo, it's `fadeOut` and added an example, the propose is to give a nice remove effect, so it doesn't just "gone" ... it's all about UI techniques, I'm used to let users know what's going on and I will never make something like disappearing a div / table row / other element without a simple effect of disappearing.

Comment: Sure me to. Take a look at my example. The user should know what is gonna happen before he clicks. But fadeOut would more looke like delete to me ;) An at least to the remove in the callback. In your example the fade animation will not have time to finish brefore the element is gonna be removed.

Comment: bind is deprecated, use on.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.minibox').click(function () {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Check out [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery to register your event it is as easy as:

```
$(".minibox").click(function(){
   $(this).remove();
});
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/fsYtY/).**

Answer (score 1):

your html:

```
<div class="box">some content</div>
<div class="box">some content</div>
<div class="box">some content</div>
<div class="box">some content</div>
ect...
```

your jQuery

```
$(function(){ //make sure your DOM is ready
$("div.box").click(function(){ // bind click on every div that has the class box
  $(this).remove(); //remove the clicked element from the dom
});
});
```

Demo with fadeOut animation:
http://jsfiddle.net/qJHyL/1/ (and fancy delete icon)